# Sharing Powerpivot reports

Tags: sql-server, sharepoint, sharepoint-2010, powerpivot

I have generated a report in Powerpivot for excel and want to share it with other members of my team. I do not want all of them to download and install Powerpivot add-on.

I found out that the report can be shared over SharePoint 2010. For this I need to get the Powerpivot add-on for SharePoint installed as part of SQL Server. Am I right or Is there any way I can get Powerpivot to work with SharePoint? Buying SQL server just for Powerpivot add-on is not worth it because we will not be using SQL server.
Is there any other way in which I can share the report?

Comment: If you have SharePoint, then you probably already have a license for SQL Server...the question is what version of SharePoint do you have?

Comment: Also, and this is more from my own curiosity, why don't you want the users to install PowerPivot add-on?

Comment: Hi @iPolvo, we have SharePoint 2010 deployed in out company, but the IT says that powerpivot is not available and neither is SQL server. A new licence might be costly and so they are hesitant to go for it. Regarding installing Powerpivot, we have both Excel 2008 and 2010 across the team and Powerpivot does not support Excel 2008. Moreover some users are running Linux and so a web based report would be nice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I need to share my Powerpivot generated report with 5 users. One option is to have all of them install the free plug in and the $40 developer edition of SQL Server 2012 (on Amazon). You can just run that instance on your computer and have them connect to the data source via an odbc connector or Excel's built in connection wizards. Another option, although not the best, is for everyone to run a cheap dev instance on SQL Server and for you to BCP in and out the data to share it via the network or memory sticks.

The cheapest and easiest thing would be to put the dataset in Azure or Azure Marketplace and have them query the data directly via the PowerPivot plugin.

Answer (score 1):

Normally you would buy, install and use SharePoint 2010 Enterprise with the PowerPivot Service integrated to host PowerPivot workbooks on a web site.  However, there are other options.  One interesting one is purchasing hosting for PowerPivot.  Here's an [example](http://www.pivotstream.com/cloud-powerpivot/cloud-powerpivot-plan-comparison) from one hosting company.  Be sure to look closely at their pricing per number of users and data refresh needs.

Answer (score 1):

Lynn's answer is correct - you should consider either getting SharePoint, or better yet promoting the PowerPivot cubes to SQL Server 2012.

If you're hell-bent on querying data across Excel spreadsheets that contain PowerPivot cubes, then you'll need to resort to some hard-core macros. I strongly advise against it.

For a peak at how PowerPivot cubes can be connected to via code, you could try looking at the source code of [Excel Refresh Service](https://excelrefresher.codeplex.com/) on codeplex - it contains the code to open and send queries to Excel-embedded PowerPivot cubes.